# Python os.system cp command copies empty file

Tags: python

Directory 1: I have some number of txt files and one xml file which I want to change in each iteration according to txt file content.

Directory 2: I want to copy altered xml file to this directory after each iteration.

After execution I can observe the altered xml file in directory 1 which contains last txt file content as expected. However, directory 2 contains empty files with expected names.
May be there is some issue in my cp command? Could you please help?

```
os.system('cp /home/username/xmlFile.xml /home/username/NewFolder/%s.xml' % myString)
```

Entire script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
from shutil import copyfile

arr = os.listdir('/di/rec/to/ry')
newArr = []
for j in arr:
        m = re.search('.*txt', j)
        if m != None:
                newArr.append(m.group(0))
for i in newArr:
        myString = ""
        f = open('/home/username/xmlFile.xml', 'r+')
        i = i[:-4]
        data = f.readlines()
        myString += str(i)
        data[10] = data[10][:36] + i + data[10][64:]
        f.truncate(0)
        f.seek(0)
        f.writelines(data)
        #os.system('cp /home/username/xmlFile.xml /home/username/NewFolder/%s.xml' % myString)
        copyfile('/home/username/xmlFile.xml', '/home/username/NewFolder/%s.xml' % myString)
```

Comment: please post all content of python file and what is error did you get ?

Comment: Did you check the return value from `os.system()`?  Why are you using an external program to copy a file instead of the python standard library?

Comment: @cdarke I have imported python os library

Comment: `os` doesn't copy files, and `os.system()` is deprecated anyway.  Look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=copyfile#shutil.copyfile

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Actually 1st part works as I expected but I have posted anyway

Comment: @cdarke I have used shutil.copyfile now, but result is empty files again :/ I have added the code to question as well.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that you had the file open in python a well!  You are "suffering from buffering".

Comment: @cdarke sorry about that)) Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely you're encountering synchronization issues. Files aren't immediately written to disk, but buffered in memory to increase overall throughput. This means that the `copyfile` call isn't seeing the latest changes you have made the files. Try calling `f.flush()` before `copyfile` to ensure the change is committed to disk.